# Modifying appearance of dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

For the  dropdown menu, is there a way to modify the look and feel? For example, I'd like to style the text to a specific font and get rid of the natural borders on the dropdown list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do minimal customization with `CSS` the greatest effects are going to be with `jQuery`

Here is a list of great [list](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/select-box) box plugins. This [one](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/FancySelectbox) looks like the one you would like and is my personal favorite.

Comment: this plugin is not available now

Answer (score 0):

As the dropdown is an intrinsic OS control (certainly in Windows) your options are limited.

You should be able to format the border of the control but not the border of the drop down area, however, you should be able to change the font, font style and color just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Read the other answers for more control of your select box, but here is how to change the font properties, but not the drop down menu (the options)

```
select {
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size:10px;
}
```